# Como mantener las filas seleccionadas despues de cerrar y abrir la query

Tags: delphi, pascal, delphi-2010

Intento guardar el bookmark la lista de bookmark antes de cerrar la query pero al ejecutar el codigo cuando obtengo la lista esta ok, cuando cierro la query y la abro otra vez y voy a restaurar los bookmark estan vacia la lista de bookmark, mientras no cierro la query la lista esta OK.

```
procedure TForm24.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
BookmarkList: TBookmarkList;
Bookmark: TBookmark;
i: Integer;
begin
BookmarkList := DBGrid1.SelectedRows;
if BookmarkList.Count = 0 then
ShowMessage('No rows selected!')
else
begin for i := 0 to BookmarkList.Count - 1 do
begin
ClientDataSet1.GotoBookmark(BookmarkList[i]); 
end;
end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema de este código es que la `TBookmarkList` que estás utilizando es la misma (misma referencia) que tiene el `DBGrid`, por lo tanto cuando cierras la consulta, la información de esa lista se pierde.

Además esta lista, está pensada para usarla desde la clase `TCustomDBGrid` y aparentemente no tiene métodos públicos para añadir elementos o para asignar el contenido de una lista a otra. Así que puedes utilizar directamente una `TList` genérica para almacenar la lista de elementos seleccionados.

Con el siguiente código, guardamos los elementos seleccionados del `DGBrid` (`TDataset` asociado) en una lista, luego cerramos el `TDataset`, lo volvemos a abrir y recorremos la lista para seleccionarlos de nuevo.

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bookmark: TBookmark;
  i:integer;
  bList:TList<TBookmark>;
begin
  // Al ejecutar este código debe haber x líneas seleccionadas en el DbGrid...
  //----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  // Creamos la lista para almecenar los bookmarks
  bList := TList<TBookmark>.Create();
  try
    // Guardo los elementos seleccionados en la lista
    for i := 0 to (DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Count - 1) do begin
      bList.Add(DBGrid1.SelectedRows.Items[i]);
    end;

    // Si no hay ninguno, no hacemos nada más...
    if (bList.Count = 0) then begin
      ShowMessage('No rows selected!')
    end
    else begin
      // Cierro la consulta
      DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Close;
      ShowMessage('Consulta cerrada');
      // Vuelva a abrir la consulta
      DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.Open;
      ShowMessage('Consulta abierta de nueva, se van a recuperar registros seleccionados...');
      // Recorro la lista y selecciono los registros guardados...
      for i := 0 to (bList.Count - 1) do begin
        DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.GotoBookmark(bList.Items[i]);
        DBGrid1.SelectedRows.CurrentRowSelected := True;
      end;
      ShowMessage('Los se han vuelto a seleccionar');
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(bList);
  end;
end;
```

Si lo ejecutas verás un comportamiento similar a este.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: +1 Excelente respuesta Germán. Yo quizás añadiría un `if DBGrid1.DataSource.DataSet.BookmarkValid()` antes de hacer el `GotoBookmark`, para evitar que falle si algún registro ya no viene al abrir de nuevo la consulta.

Comment: Por supuesto @jachguate. Esta que comentas en una mejora. También podríamos usar un EnableControls/DisableControls antes de seleccionar para evitar refrescos innecesarios.

Comment: pues la verdad me ayudo mucho su respuesta, gracias